# Why gst_element_factory_find can't find factory "decodebin"?

Tags: c, plugins, gstreamer, missing-features

I have installed gstreamer-1.4.0 in order to create simple app for decoding video files.
The pipeline which I try to create looks simple:

```
filesrc location="file.h264" ! decodebin ! filesink location="file.raw"
```

This pipeline works fine when i launch it using gst-launch-1.0, however when I try to run my program written in C, it cannot find factory called "decodebin".

```
GstElementFactory *factory;
factory = gst_element_factory_find("decodebin");
if( !factory )
    // fail
```

Above code always fails (factory is NULL). gst-inspect-1.0 recognizes "decodebin" correctly, so my guess is that something's wrong with GST_PLUGIN_PATH or something similar, but I have no idea how should I configure it properly. But it's just my guess based on the fact that my app creates other elements from factories such as filesrc or filesink which are in plugin called coreelements, and still decodebin which is from plugin 'playback' failes.

**My question: How can i fix my gstreamer configuration in order to recognize all plugins, not just coreelements?**

If i skipped some important info please let me know so that I could append it asap :)

// EDIT:
Let's say i've installed gstreamer from sources (i'm using ubuntu 14.04).
I've also installed all plugins (base, bag, good), also from sources.
Installation directory was /opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/, maybe this causes some problem.

If I execute command:

```
echo $GST_PLUGINS_PATH
```

all I get is an empty line, similar effect when i try to display values of other GST_* environmental variables.

**more specific question: Which directories should I append to which variables in order to make non coreelements plugins work?**

And if this question is too general, than:

**how gst_element_factory_find("factory_name") checks if a given factory exists?**

Comment: Knowing how gst was installed would be helpful, I guess. Also, in your place, I'd try running examples shipped with the installation (starting from simpler ones), and see if (and where) they break, paying special attention to initialization and such things.

Comment: @mlvljr there is a slight problem with telling you how i've installed gst, since I used my company's bash script to do that. The person responsible for this script is currently unavailable, thus i can't ask him for any suggestions / fixing script.

Comment: okay then, glad you fixed that, anyways :)

Comment: @mlvjr Maybe you know about some tutorial/articles/info about configuring gstreamer environmental variableS? That would be very helpful :)

Comment: well, I followed the "uninstalled gst" script here, and it worked (after I agreed to go with the defaults and have it in my home folder), there were some issues with the compilation order though (you have to run autogen.sh for gst-lbav only after the plugins are all both configured and built, as there's some dependency on auto-generated headers there, also, to build bad or ugly plugins, I had to explicitly add the option enabling desktop OpenGL).

Comment: within the uninstalled env., after running respective .sh that is to set the env. vars, everything compiles fine. I'm going to reinstall Ubuntu though soon, and go for side-by-side gst 0.1 and 1.0 installs, so we'll see how that works too, soon :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if what i did fixed everything, but for now i solved my problem by copying libplayback.so and other compiled plugins binaries to the folder with libcoreelements.so

It appears that the problem was caused by the non-standard installation directories,
so my solution is a hotfix, since I still don't know how was it possible that gst-inspect-1.0 recognized all plugins whilst gst_element_factory_find() couldn't. Any further inside will be appreciated :)